# XSLT decrease variable

Tags: xslt

I have a variable where I have saved my let's say publications. This variable has multiple items in itself. Then I group these publications by year and each year sort by name. But I would like the counter to ignore the grouping and count from the oldest publication to the newest one ignoring the groups.

Basically I need the functionality as is displayed below but I know that you cannot do $counter-1. Is there some workaround if I do not want to use saxon?

```
<xsl:variable name="author" select="." />
<xsl:variable name="publications" select="$dblp/*[(author|editor)=$author]" />
<h1><xsl:value-of select="." /></h1>
<xsl:variable name="counter">
    <xsl:value-of select="count($publications[author=$author])"/>
</xsl:variable>



<table border="1" width="100%">
<!-- for each year select that year and print-->
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($publications/year)">
<xsl:sort select="." order="descending" />
<xsl:variable name="year" select="."/>
<tr><th bgcolor="#FFFFCC" align="center" colspan="100%"><xsl:value-of select="$year" />    </th>
</tr>

<!-- for publications in that year print the info about them-->
<xsl:for-each select="$publications/title[../year=$year]">
    <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />       
     <tr>
        <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="$counter-1" />
```

Comment: The `xsl:number` element might help you, I suppose. Haven't used it myself though.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your starting point (the source XML, or at least the content of the processed variable) and explain what is the desired output. Also state which version of XSLT are you using.

Comment: You certainly can "do $counter-1", but you cannot decrement the variable. Can you explain better what you want to accomplish?

Comment: A minor detail, if you want the value of $counter minus one, you have to put spaces around the minus sign, because hyphens are allowed in XML (and therefore XPath) names.